# Changing -- INSERT (lang) --

Tags: key-bindings

When keymap is set and iminsert is 1, it says `-- INSERT (lang) --` at the bottom of the screen.  Is there an easy way to change this string (or just the `lang` string)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you exactly mean with "change this string"; always change it globally? Change it depending on a setting? Change it at will?

At any rate, the `INSERT` text is inserted with gettext in `screen.c`, around line 10,049:

```
MSG_PUTS_ATTR(_(" INSERT"), attr);
```

The `(lang)` part is added in a similar way a few lines later (with some cruft removed):

```
if (State & LANGMAP)
{
        MSG_PUTS_ATTR(_(" (lang)"), attr);
}
```

So you can change this text from a gettext po file (or just change the C source and recompile), but then it's *always* changed.

Comment: @Lawrence Changing the gettext files would not strictly be "recompiling" ;-) And because the default of `en` doesn't seem to have an existing `.po`/`.mo` file, the changes could actually stick between upgrades ... But no, it's not simply a setting or some such...

Comment: Thanks. I meant change it globally always. Don't know what a gettext po file is, but I am now content that this is not easy enough to be worth doing (for me; maybe it _is_ easy). (deleted above and edited)

Comment: @Lawrence Not entirely sure how to go about it either; I just know it can be done :-) IMHO this is is too small of an issue for me to spend a lot of time on ;-)